# Developer Access to Google Assistant Conversation History

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am developing a Google Assistant app for Google Home, and about to launch the app. I am wondering, once my app is live on the Google Assistant platform, whether I (as a developer) would have access to all of the conversation histories as users interact with my app.

If so, does Actions on Google / Google have some sort of interface to view / download the history? Or, do I have to log and capture the history myself? I thought the history will be really helpful for me to improve my app.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how you have built your Action.

If you have built it with one of the templates - then no, you don't have access to the conversations.

If you have built it with the Actions SDK or with Dialogflow, then you will have access to quite a bit of information that is delivered to your fulfillment webhook. If you have intents that do not send anything to your webhook - you will not get that information.

There are tools that help you examine conversation flow, see where users get stuck or fall out of the conversation, or how they're using your Action. Most of them have good integration with the Actions on Google libraries. I use a combination of Chatbase, Dashbot.io, and Google Analytics.